# What do I do with the Device collection in Apigee

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas

What can I do with the default collection "Device" in Apigee BaaS?

The docu says 
http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/default-data-entities
The device entity represents a unique device that is being used to access your app. Device entities should be associated with a user entity. The API Services push notification feature requires the device entity.

How do I really fill the Device collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way to fill this collection is by using one of the Apigee BaaS SDKs. When installed on a mobile device, you can trigger a device registration which will include the unique device ID and a push token.

You can read more about it in the [Apigee docs](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/managing-users-and-devices).